# Project managemnt app what to show when user is yet to create his first project?

Tags: website-design

I am working on a project management web app. When a user registers on the site after successfull registration I log him in and redirect him to the Projects listings.

Now since he is a new user and has no projected created yet. I can do one of the two and which one and why is my question.

**Option 1**
I could show a message like 'No project added yet, create one to get started' and an option to create a project.

**Option 2**
When loading the project listing page if I find that there are no projects i can redirect the user to create the project first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the two options you suggest, I'd go with number one for the simple reason that auto-forwarding can be disorientating.

A third option is to put in a sample project for them to play with.

Comment: Sample project which then further contain sample bugs looks like a very good thing to do. User would be able to explore what all features the site has to offer without actually going and creating entities on his own. Thanks

Comment: Just remember to keep the sample, simple. You don't want to overwhelm the user or get into the really complex stuff: just give them an idea of "What does the product look like when being used properly?"

Answer (score 2):

This is an awesome question on user on boarding. 
In most cases, users understand best when provided with an example. 
I can derive examples from games, where before you are pushed into actual missions, you are given step by step instructions to get accustomed to the key combinations and moves.

@yasser As you have mentioned in your comment, the user finds it easy when he first works on a sample project. This gives him a practical overview of the work area, actions and data. You can refer apps like Projectplace, Trello, etc for examples.

Comment: It should cover most probable scenarios. Usually it explains 20% features of an app which are used 80%of the time